# Why does installing imbalanced-learn library work if it's done via Conda but not if it's via Pip3? Why are Conda and Pip different for this?

Tags: scikit-learn, pip, conda, imblearn

I'm working in Jupyter Notebook and using the following versions:

Python 3.11.5, pip 23.2.1, conda 23.7.4, scikit-learn 1.3.0 during both pip3 and conda installations, and imbalanced-learn 0.11.0 in installations via both pip3 and conda as well.

So, after successfully installing **imbalanced-learn** library via **Pip3**,

```
pip install imblearn
```

when I attempted to import SMOTE algorithm from imblearn.over_sampling module in my Python notebook,

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
```

I unexpectedly encountered an Import Error, stating that:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_MissingValues' from 'sklearn.utils._param_validation
```

Fortunately, subsequently un-installing imbalanced-learn and then proceeding to install it again, using **Conda** this time, resulted in no error from there onwards:

1. `pip uninstall imblearn --yes`
2. `conda install -c conda-forge imbalanced-learn`

So, after encountering and then resolving this issue, I tried finding out the reason why this happens in the first place. Unfortunately, I found nothing concrete behind this discrepancy. So, why are Conda and Pip different for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per duplicate, it has to do with lack of version constraints in `imbalanced-learn`. Perhaps more could be said specifically to the question, *"Why are Conda and Pip different for this?"*, but since no versions are documented in OP, this is not reproducible. Would be happy to consider reopening were versions of `scikit-learn` and `imbalanced-learn` in both Pip and Conda cases added to question body.

Comment: Thank you @merv . Question body has been updated.

Comment: I cannot recreate the error with the reported versions. Without reproducible steps to recreate the issue, there isn't motivation to reopen. This is a known incompatibility that impacted `imbalanced-learn<0.11` when combined with `scikit-learn>=1.3`. The resolution is either to upgrade to `imbalanced-learn>=0.11.0` or downgrade to `scikit-learn<1.3`. Are you absolutely sure that the first environment did not have `imbalanced-learn <0.11`?